# php 8.1 - return type deprecated in older script

Tags: php, deprecated, arrayaccess, php-8.1

Trying to update to php 8.1 and noticed this deprecated notice showing up in the error logs I'd like to take care of.

`[14-Feb-2022 14:48:25 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of TLDExtractResult::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home/example/public_html/assets/tldextract/tldextract.php on line 299`

I was able to suppress the warning, but would actually like to update the script so there are no issues in the future.

```
//public function offsetExists($offset) {
//  return array_key_exists($offset, $this->fields);
//}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function offsetExists(mixed $offset) {
    return array_key_exists($offset, $this->fields);
}
```

Here is the section of code in question :

```
class TLDExtractResult implements ArrayAccess {
    private $fields;

    public function __construct($subdomain, $domain, $tld) {
        $this->fields = array(
            'subdomain' => $subdomain,
            'domain'    => $domain,
            'tld'       => $tld,
        );
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if ( array_key_exists($name, $this->fields) ) {
            return $this->fields[$name];
        }
        throw new OutOfRangeException(sprintf('Unknown field "%s"', $name));
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->fields);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        throw new LogicException('Can\'t modify an immutable object.');
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return sprintf('%s(subdomain=\'%s\', domain=\'%s\', tld=\'%s\')', __CLASS__, $this->subdomain, $this->domain, $this->tld);
    }

    //public function offsetExists($offset) {
    //  return array_key_exists($offset, $this->fields);
    //}
    
    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function offsetExists(mixed $offset) {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->fields);
    }

    //public function offsetGet($offset) {
    //  return $this->__get($offset);
    //}

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function offsetGet(mixed $offset) {
        return $this->__get($offset);
    }

    //public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
    //  throw new LogicException(sprintf('Can\'t modify an immutable object. You tried to set "%s".', $offset));
    //}

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function offsetSet(mixed $offset, $value) {
        throw new LogicException(sprintf('Can\'t modify an immutable object. You tried to set "%s".', $offset));
    }

    //public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    //  throw new LogicException(sprintf('Can\'t modify an immutable object. You tried to unset "%s".', $offset));
    //}

    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function offsetUnset(mixed $offset) {
        throw new LogicException(sprintf('Can\'t modify an immutable object. You tried to unset "%s".', $offset));
    }

    /**
     * Get the domain name components as a native PHP array.
     * The returned array will contain these keys: 'subdomain', 'domain' and 'tld'.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray() {
        return $this->fields;
    }
}
```

What exactly does php 8.1 not like here?  This is a little above what I typically do with php and not exactly sure of the issue.  It sounds like a specific return type needs specified?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+PHP+Deprecated+Return+type+attribute+should+be+used+to+temporarily+suppress+the+notice Also, such things are typically included in the release notes of a new version.

Comment: I have made a reference Q&A for this message, to avoid having lots of duplicates with slightly different examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71133749/157957

Comment: @IMSoP - very good information and explanation - thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can specify return types that match those indicated for the various methods of the `ArrayAccess` interface as shown [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). For example, like this for the specific method in the deprecation message in your question:

```
public function offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool {
    return array_key_exists($offset, $this->fields);
}
```

Comment: So it is literally as easy as changing these to match what is shown in the manual?  `public offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool`, `public offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed`, `public offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void`, `public offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void` - is that correct?

Comment: In this case, I think that's probably true. There are more details to dealing with this situation in general that I think IMSoP's new answer covers very well.

Comment: Great - thank you for the clarification.